# For a finite cyclic group G with generator g and subgroup H where g^a is the smallest positive power of g in H, H contains all positive powers of g^a

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Am I right in thinking that since H is a cyclic subgroup, then h=g^a is a generator of H?  Therefore it must contain all positive powers of h.

Comment: Isn't that implicit in the definition of subgroup?

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense too.  H is closed under its composition law.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct.

To see why this is the case, suppose it was greater than the order of $g^a$. Then that means that there is a $g^b$ in H with $b>a$ such that its order is greater.

But if we operate it with $g^{-a}$ (which is in $H$ since subgroups are closed under inverses) some number of times we get $g^{b-ak}\in H$, with $0 < b-ak<=a$.

If $b-ak=a$, then the order of $g^b$ must be less than or equal to $a$, since $g^b$ is the k+1th power of $g^a$.

If $0 < b-ak < a$ then $g^{b-ak}$ is in H and is smaller than a, contradicting the hypothesis.